# Can I change Evelyn Parker's fate?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Evelyn Parker is a character you get intel from early in the game, and then later have to save as a result of your heist gone wrong. After the rescue she stays at Judy's apartment to recover

> until later in the game when she kills herself.

Can I change Evelyn Parker's fate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to save Evelyn Parker.

Story spoilers:

> You have no control over any of the events leading to her death, and her death is even a prerequisite for you to continue Judy's storyline.